# Update dataframe column with values from another dataframe by index

Tags: pandas

I have two DataFrames.

One of them contains: `item id`, `name`, `quantity` and `price`. 
Another: `item id`, `name` and `quantity`.

The problem is to update names and quantity in first DataFrame taking information from the second DataFrame by item id. Also, first DataFrame has not all item id's, so I need to take into account only those rows from the second DataFrame, which are in the first one.

#### DataFrame 1

```
In [1]: df1
Out[1]: 
   id  name quantity price 
0  10  X    10       15  
1  11  Y    30       20  
2  12  Z    20       15  
3  13  X    15       10  
4  14  X    12       15
```

#### DataFrame 2

```
In [2]: df2
Out[2]: 
   id  name quantity
0  10  A    3       
1  12  B    3       
2  13  C    6
```

---

I've tried to use `apply` to iterate through rows and modify column value by condition like this:

```
def modify(row):
    row['name'] = df2[df2['id'] == row['id']]['name'].get_values()[0]
    row['quantity'] = df2[df2['id'] == row['id']]['quantity'].get_values()[0]

df1.apply(modify, axis=1)
```

But it doesn't have any results. DataFrame 1 is still the same

---

I am expecting something like this first:

```
In [1]: df1
Out[1]: 
   id  name quantity price 
0  10  A    3        15  
1  11  Y    30       20  
2  12  B    3        15  
3  13  C    6        10  
4  14  X    12       15
```

After that I want to drop the rows, which were not modified to get:

```
In [1]: df1
Out[1]: 
   id  name quantity price 
0  10  A    3        15  
1  12  B    3        15  
2  13  C    6        10
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `update`

```
df1=df1.set_index('id')
df1.update(df2.set_index('id'))
df1=df1.reset_index()
Out[740]: 
   id name  quantity  price
0  10    A       3.0     15
1  11    Y      30.0     20
2  12    B       3.0     15
3  13    C       6.0     10
4  14    X      12.0     15
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
new_df = df.merge(df2, on='id')
new.drop(['name_x','quantity_x'], inplace=True, axis=1)
new.columns = ['id','price','name','quantity']
```

**Output**

```
   id  price name  quantity
0  10     15    A         3
1  12     15    B         3
2  13     10    C         6
```